# Grunt doesn't show what file caused it to fail

Tags: gruntjs

I'm using the postcss plugin for grunt (https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-postcss), where I use cssnano for minification as following:

```
postcss: {
      test: {
        src: [
          'dist/**/*.css'
        ],
        options: {
          map: true,
          failOnError: true,
          processors: [
            require('autoprefixer')({
              overrideBrowserslist: ['last 1 version']
            }),
            require('cssnano')()
          ]
        },
      },
```

When there are some errors during minification I get that in the grunt output, but I don't get what file caused the error:

[image]

How can I make grunt to show me the file that caused it to fail ?

Comment: Maybe try adding grunt's [`--verbose`](https://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli#verbose-v) option/flag to the `grunt` command.

Comment: @RobC yeah I tried that, It doesn't work :(